# Despite app.listen, express app does not bind to port

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

Exactly what it sounds like.
I use ExpressJS for my Node app, which is hosted on Heroku.
Despite using app.listen, it consistently is getting / causing [heroku R10 errors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout), which are caused by a web app not binding to `process.env.PORT` in time.

The relevant code:

```
const app = express();
var isRoot = (process.getuid && (process.getuid() === 0));
var port;
if (isRoot) {
    port = 80;
} else {
    port = process.env.PORT | 8000;
}
const server = app.listen(port, onStartup);
function onStartup() {
    console.log("Started webserver on port "+port);
}
```

Now the odd thing is, I'm getting the "Started webserver on port [foo]" message, it's just not binding to the port.

Logs:

```
2020-03-30T19:50:39.434302+00:00 app[web.1]: > foo-bar@1.0.0 start /app
2020-03-30T19:50:39.434303+00:00 app[web.1]: > node scrape2.js
2020-03-30T19:50:39.434303+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-30T19:50:39.829882+00:00 app[web.1]: Verbose mode OFF
2020-03-30T19:50:39.830782+00:00 app[web.1]: Started webserver on port 8052
2020-03-30T19:51:37.415192+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-30T19:51:37.293060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-03-30T19:51:37.293142+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-03-30T19:51:37.391762+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Help!

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR operator. You probably wanted to use `||` , to fall back on port 8000 whenever process.env.port is undefined.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify which port the process is supposed to be started on: 80 or `process.env.port`? Also, log shows error R10, but question texts mentions R16.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `|` and R16 typos - yes, it's supposed to be R10, I have no idea how R16 got there. I'm trying to bind to `process.env.PORT`, because Heroku kills any web processes that don't bind to it within 60 seconds of bootup. The bitwise operator was the issue, changed that and now it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a stupid and accidentally used the bitwise OR operator, which caused it to bind to a different port than `process.env.PORT`. Changed it from `|` to `||` and it works fine now.